# How to add a library in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll, nlopt

Iam new to C++ and I am trying to add NLopt library to C++ using VS 2013. NLopt is a non-linear optimization library (http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_C-plus-plus_Reference#Compiling_and_linking_your_program_to_NLopt). NLopt has a DLL file and .h file and I cannot figure out a way to get them work. I appreciate if anyone can give me a quick guide on how to import this library.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify, be more specific, cite exact errors, of "cannot...to get them work."

Comment: I am assuming the code compiles and links.  So the real issue is finding the dll when you execute the program. This is determined by the dll search path in Windows.  Here is a link to a knowledge base article from Microsoft about the DLL search path. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18(v=vs.110).aspx.  Make sure the NLopt DLL is in one of the places windows looks for it.

Comment: Thank you Mark. That should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you'd want to go through: DLLs in Visual C++ - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ez7dh12.aspx

More specifically, gauging from your question you are probably looking for Implicit Linking - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14wsce5.aspx

And if all of that sounds confusing to you, you might go through this walk-through first: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235636.aspx