# Setting up NLOpt when working from windows cmd prompt

Tags: c++, windows, dll, nlopt

I am writing a c++ program from the windows cmd prompt, and compiling with mingw (`g++`). This program needs a non-linear optimiser and [NLOpt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt) looks like a good choice. I learnt c++ for a uni course, so the environment I was using was already set up, I have no experience in setting up libraries etc.

So far my steps have been;

1. Download the precompiled DLLs for 64-bit windows (which is what I'm running) from [here](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_on_Windows).
2. Run the command `dlltool --input-def libnlopt-0.def --dllname libnlopt-0.dll --output-lib libnlopt-0.lib` (from the [same page](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_on_Windows)), which ran without errors.

This creates an .hpp file, however, when I try to `#include` the file I get

```
In file included from optimiseDogs.cc:9:0:
C:\Files|Development\NLOpt2.4.2\nlopt.hpp:29:19: fatal error: nlopt.h: Nosuch file or directory
#include <nlopt.h>
```

`nlopt.h` and `nlopt.hpp` are in the same directory as each other. My program is in a different folder.
[image: image of folder setup]

This is probably really basic, sorry to trouble you with it. Perhaps I am not completely alone in my ignorance and this will help someone else too. Also, I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105690/how-to-add-a-library-in-c), but it deals with installing on visual basic, and I'm not using a GUI, just notepad++ and the cmd prompt.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I didn't downvote it.... is nlopt.h in same directory? Can you post file structure?

Comment: Its in the same directory as nlopt.hpp, not the same as my program.

Comment: I think that they should be same... check once again

Comment: @AjayKulkarni surely the program is not meant to be in the same directory as the library?

Comment: Well... program and your optimizer needs to be in same directory because you're using external optimizer.

Comment: What is your compiling command/path that gives error?

Comment: The compiling command I'm using is `g++ optimiseFood.cc readRawFiles.cc saveData.cc manualIn.cc scoreNutrient.cc nutrients.cc checkAll.cc randomGuess.cc -o optimiseFood.exe`, so it dosn't include any part of the optimiser

Comment: You are not linking your program with `libnlopt-0.dll`. In their site they say you should link it against `nlop` and `math` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in `windows` and using `mingw`: downloaded zip archive already contains `.dll` and `.lib` files. So you dont need to run `dlltool` which creates these `.lib`,`.dll` from `.def`. I think your problem is compiling command using `g++` adding include and library path directives.

```
C:\Files\Development\NLOpt2.4.2>g++ <path_of_source>.cc -o program.exe -L. -lnlopt -lm -I. -I<path_of_your_headers>
```

I encounted in the past that order of `-I` and `-L` may matter so try changing if not working.
Please see [this tut](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Tutorial#Example_in_C.2FC.2B.2B) and [that tut](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampledll#toc1) to understand the concept.

Comment: when you say `<path_of_your_headers.` do you man the headers for the optimiser (`nlopt.h` and `nlopt.hpp`) or the headers that are in my program?

Comment: If you build it in optimiser folder it contains optimiser header so `-I.` means use current directory for optimiser header. `-I<path_of_your_headers>` means use `path_of_your_headers` directory for your own header files.